# Node.js - promises and conidtional statements (if, switch, etc) - how to structure?

Tags: javascript, node.js, architecture, promise, structure

Can you recommend how to correctly deal with a control flow with many if/switch and promises? All the tutorials on the Internet that I've found tend to deal with simple control flow, without many (any?) different processing branches. Any suggested reading or at least search terms?

The way I do it now is to encapsulate if/switch logic in a function that returns a Promise after evaluating the conditions and returns to the main process loop. Any way to do it better, nicer?

Sample code:

```
// Check if argument is a valid URL
Promise.promisify(checkUrl)().then(() => {
        // Delete all query parameters from URL if present
        return sanitizer.cleanAsync(argv.url)
    }).then(_cleanUrl => {
        cleanUrl = _cleanUrl;
        logger.warn(`URL: ${cleanUrl}`);
        // Validate Google Analytics view id supplied as '--gaId=<id>' command line argument or exit if it is not present
        return Promise.promisify(checkGaId)()
    }).then(() => {
        // Check if DB exists, if not create it
        return db.checkIfDatabaseExistsAsync()
    }).then(() => {
        // Check if all tables exist, if not create them
        return db.checkTablesAsync()
    }).then(() => {
        // Check DB integrity (possiblDelete all query parameters from URL if presente to turn off in the config)
        if (config.database.checkIntegrity) {
            return db.integrityChecksAsync();
        }
    }).then(() => {
        // Check if URL already exists in DB, if not insert it
        return db.getOrCreateEntryUrlIdAsync(cleanUrl)
    }).then(_entryId => {
        entryId = _entryId;
        // Check if any previous executions for the entry point exist and if so whether the last one completed
        return db.getLastExecutionDataAsync(entryId);
    }).then(lastExecution => {
        // If last execution was not completed prompt for user action
        return processLastExecution(entryId, lastExecution)
    }).then(_pages => {
       ... more code follows here...
```

And psuedo-code for `processLasExecution` function:

```
function processLastExecution(entryId, lastExecution) {
return new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {

        // No previous executions found or all was okay
        if (lastExecution == null || (lastExecution != null && lastExecution.is_completed == 'Y')) {

            ...resolves with A;

        } else {

            Promise.promisify(selectRunOption)().then(option => {

                switch (option) {

                    case 'resume':

                        ...resolves with B;
                        break;
                    case 'ignore':

                        ...resolves with C;
                        break;
                    case 'delete':

                        ...resolves with D;
                        break;
                    default:
                        ...rejects
                }
            });
        }
    }
)
```

}

Any way of having the if/switch logic better/more clearly encapsulated or served?

Oh, if anyone wonders this is a command line script, not a web application, and this not exactly what Node.js was intended for.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use generator, then you can write sync like codes:

```
co(function* () {
   // Check if argument is a valid URL
   if (yield checkUrl) {
       var cleanUrl = yield sanitizer.cleanAsync(argv.url);
       ...
   }
   ...
}, ...
```

co can cooperation with callback and promise, see https://github.com/tj/co

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I'd rather stick with Promises and not add more dependencies if they are not necessary.